# How to upload a custom Build Task to TFS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, release-management, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a custom build task ready to go and I would like to upload it to my TFS server.  I don't see much guidance out there for how to do this.  Is there any way it can be uploaded through some kind of an "Add Task" workflow in the UI, or does it need to be done via the TFS2015 instance API?

Any step-by-step instructions would be appreciated.

FYI, I'm using the following visual studio template:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JoshGarverick.VSTSExtensionProjectTemplates

I'd like to see it here:

[image]

Comment: Did you refer to the extension documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task

Comment: @DanielMann - yes.  I don't want to publish my extension - I want to install it on my instance of TFS only.

Comment: Then don't publish it. You have to upload extension VSIX files to TFS 2015 anyway. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have packaged the extension (custom build task), then just need to upload the extension VSIX files to TFS 2015 as mentioned by Daniel, then install the extension. After completed the installation the custome task step will displayed there.

Go to `http://server:8080/tfs/_gallery/manage` to upload the extension

[image]